# Flatten nested json with Spark

Tags: python, json, scala, apache-spark

I have this nested JSON:

> {"duration": 1864, "plates": [{"car": {"bodyStyle": [{"confidence": 74.86398, "name": "s*****"}], "color": [{"confidence": 81.53036, "name": "s*****"}], "makeModelYear": [{"confidence": 94.14993, "name": null}], "warpedBox": [28.75753, 52.94751, 473.7732, 52.94751, 473.7732, 307.5584, 28.75753, 307.5584]}, "confidences": [89.91024], "country": {"code": "FRA", "confidence": 99.97168, "name": "France", "state": null}, "text": ["FL040B*"], "warpedBox": [78.9483, 162.2646, 172.6279, 162.2646, 172.6279, 217.0638, 78.9483, 217.0638]}], "timestamp": "2022-03-24T21:55:42.613327"}

The schema:

```
root
 |-- duration: long (nullable = true)
 |-- plates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- car: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- bodyStyle: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- color: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- makeModelYear: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- warpedBox: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- confidences: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- text: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- warpedBox: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried many ways to flatten the structure, but it's not a success :

```
// read json log json data :
val DF = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(path)
DF.printSchema()

val explodedDF = DF.select(explode(col("plates")).as("plates"))

val finalDF = explodedDF.select(col("plates.*"))
  .select("car", "car.*")
finalDF.show()
```

out of the code :

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|                 car|           bodyStyle|               color|makeModelYear|           warpedBox|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
|[[[74.86398, s***...|[[74.86398, s*****]]|[[81.53036, s*****]]|[[94.14993,]]|[28.75753, 52.947...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------------+
```

Has anyone encountered this type of nested JSON in Scala or Python?

Comment: Explode annumber times.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed like this :

1 - Explode all structure in the same level

```
    // Explode DF level 1 :
val explodedDFL1 = DF.select(explode(
  col("plates")).as("plate"),
  col("duration").as("duration"),
  col("timestamp").as("timestamp"))
```

2 - Explode the deep nested (plate) structure base on the DataFrame exploded in step 1

```
// Explode DF level 2 :
val explodedDFL2 = explodedDFL1.select(
  col("duration"),
  col("timestamp"),
  col("plate.car.bodyStyle.confidence").as("bodyStyle_confidence"),
  col("plate.car.bodyStyle.name").as("bodyStyle_name"),
  col("plate.car.color.confidence").as("color_confidence"),
  col("plate.car.color.name").as("color_name"),
  col("plate.car.makeModelYear.confidence").as("makeModelYear_confidence"),
  col("plate.car.makeModelYear.name").as("makeModelYear_name"),
  col("plate.car.warpedBox").as("plate_warpedBox"),
  col("plate.confidences").as("plate_confidence"),
  col("plate.country.code").as("country_code"),
  col("plate.country.confidence").as("country_confidence"),
  col("plate.country.name").as("country_name"),
  col("plate.country.state").as("country_state"),
  col("plate.text").as("plate_text"),
  col("plate.warpedBox").as("plate_warpedBox_2")
)
explodedDFL2.printSchema()
```

Then the output :

```
root
 |-- duration: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
 |-- bodyStyle_confidence: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- bodyStyle_name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- color_confidence: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- color_name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- makeModelYear_confidence: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- makeModelYear_name: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- plate_warpedBox: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- plate_confidence: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |-- country_code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country_confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |-- country_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- country_state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- plate_text: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- plate_warpedBox_2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```